# KDTree Function only works once

Tags: python

I'm using `mathutils.kdtree.KDTree` within a function to find the closest vertex to a particular location, and then extrude it to that exact point.

When I call the function to operate on one mesh it works perfectly, but when I subsequently call the same function to operate on another mesh, it has no effect.

There's no difference between the two meshes that would cause one to fail. I've tried swapping the order, and it's always the second mesh that is unaffected by the function.

I'm wondering whether the KDTree has to be specifically destroyed after use (perhaps when I add the second mesh's vertices it appends them to the tree formed from the first mesh?). I've tried setting it to `None` at the end of the function, but without success.

I can't find much more detail [in the docs](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_70_release/mathutils.kdtree.html).

Here's how the tree is being used:

```
import mathutils

def add_corner_verts(feature_name):
    mesh = bpy.data.objects[feature_name].data
    size = len(mesh.vertices)
    kd = mathutils.kdtree.KDTree(size)
    for i, v in enumerate(mesh.vertices):
        kd.insert(v.co, i)
    kd.balance()

    # kd.find() and extrude stuff

    # kd = None # Adding this didn't seem to help
```

Does anyone know why a KDTree might only work the first time?

Comment: Fixed it. Nothing to do with `kdtree` after all, but an intervening function I called was changing `mesh.select_mode` to FACE when `add_corner_verts` required it to be VERT. Silly me.